# What does $request->input('field', []) means?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm new with laravel and I am rewriting the entire web post routes to API.

As the title says, what does `$request->input('field', [])` means?

and what is the difference between `$request->field` and `$request->input('field', [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value):

```php
$request->input('field', [])
```

means that you want to get the value of `field`, but if it is not present then you will get the default value, which you can set in the second parameter. In this case, empty array.

`$request->field` and `$request->input('field', [])` are quite the same, but in the `$request->field` you can't set the default value if the input is missing.

Comment: thanks @adriankokot, will accept this answer in 5mins.

Comment: in addition tho, can I use `input` method in a `non Http/Request` key pair value? `(e.g, $array['field'])` ?

Comment: well, not really. `input` method is a part of `Illuminate\Http\Request`. But in Laravel there's also the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class, you may want to look at it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

Answer (score 1):

The request->input($key, $default) uses 2 Keys

First one is the request key and the second one is a default value, which can be used if the first value is not defined.